# Ruby on rails plugin - Intellij idea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

So, I"m using intellij idea community addition for ruby on rails development. I installed intellij, ruby, etc. on my computer. However, when I try to install the ruby on rails plugin in intellij after clicking on opening the plugin manager and clicking "install intellij plugins" there is no plugin from the list which is called "ruby plugin." I tried several of the plugins from this website :https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1293?pr= 
....selecting the "install from disk" option. None of them worked.
help please.

Comment: Did you try RubyMine? It does not have community edition though (

Comment: RubyMine is just a stripped down IDEA with the Ruby plugin pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby development is only supported in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, not in the Community Edition.